# How to select sub query in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to select subquery in pl/sql by count where UPI debit card and VISA debit cards as screenshot below:

Please helps to check script code as below :

```
for r in (select BRANCHCODE,BRANCHNAME,cntupi

          from ACTIVE_CARD_DEBIT_CREDIT_PER_B as man,
             (select up.BRANCHNAME,count(*)cupi from vw_upi1 up
               where up.PREFIX = '8877'
               and up.BRANCHNAME = man.BRANCHNAME
               group by up.BRANCHNAME
             )as cntupi,
           (select v.BRANCHNAME,count(*)cupi from vw_visa v
               where v.PREFIX = '9966'
               and v.BRANCHNAME = man.BRANCHNAME
               group by v.BRANCHNAME
             )as cntvisa,
          where expirydate>vToDate and createdate<=vToDate and nvl(closedate,vToDate+1)>vToDate

          group by BRANCHCODE,BRANCHNAME
          order by BRANCHCODE,BRANCHNAME
         ) loop
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to not use `AS` while table aliasing as we can for column aliasing. Also there is a comma (`,`) after `cntvisa` alias which should not be there.

I modified your query in order to remove syntax errors.

```
select BRANCHCODE,BRANCHNAME,cntupi
          from ACTIVE_CARD_DEBIT_CREDIT_PER_B man,
             (select up.BRANCHNAME,count(*)cupi from vw_upi1 up
               where up.PREFIX = '8877'
               and up.BRANCHNAME = man.BRANCHNAME
               group by up.BRANCHNAME
             ) cntupi,
           (select v.BRANCHNAME,count(*)cupi from vw_visa v
               where v.PREFIX = '9966'
               and v.BRANCHNAME = man.BRANCHNAME
               group by v.BRANCHNAME
             ) cntvisa 
          where expirydate>vToDate and createdate<=vToDate and nvl(closedate,vToDate+1)>vToDate
          group by BRANCHCODE,BRANCHNAME
          order by BRANCHCODE,BRANCHNAME
```